# How to receive a callback that message has been received in google play games services for unity?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, unity-game-engine

Is there a way that I can confirm that a message has been received by an opponent when using `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.SendMessage()` .

Also does the code after `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RealTime.SendMessage()` gets called immediately or does it wait until the message has been received ?

**I'm using google's official google play games services for unity plugin.**

Answer (score 2):

The short answer, is no, there is not a return value to SendMessage().  The call is more or less synchronous, meaning once it returns the message will be sent.  There is no interaction with the receiver to confirm the message.

If you need something like that, it is best to implement your own protocol on top of SendMessage().  You can keep a list of messages sent and periodically the receiver could send the ids of the messages received.

Alternatively, you could have some sort of serial number and have the receiver send an error to the sender if a serial number is skipped.